# array.includes($store.state.propertyvalue) not updating with vuex state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using `[].includes($store.state.propertyvalue)` to check if a user-selected value is in a list that then controls whether other form elements are visible or not with `v-if`. However, this is not updating correctly when that value is set or changes.

I even tried moving it to a computed value in my component (and adding `this` to the front of `$store`), but it doesn't update properly there either. Any insights?

In my component:

```
computed: {
    paymentNeeded: function() {
        return [1,9].includes(this.$store.state.membership_type);
    },
},
```

In my store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    membership_type: false,
  }
},
mutations: {
   UPDATE_STATE (state, payload) {
       Vue.set(state, payload.name, payload.value);
   },
},
```

An `<option>` group with selects of values 1–9 go through `UPDATE_STATE` successfully in my code (checked with Vue tools to monitor state), changing the value from `false` to an integer.

Comment: Best guess is that it isn't present in the initial `state` so it isn't reactive. Beyond that you'd need to post significantly more code. Better still, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I initialize the properties in my store with `false`, since I use that to hide other form parts till those properties evaluate to not-false with an integer value in them. I even change the property value with `Vue.set` to ensure that reactivity is maintained. Everything else about the reactivity of the form works, as form components show and hide with `v-if` according to changes in those properties. It's just the `array.includes()` that is never working.

Comment: You need to post some code. There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're trying to do so it is most likely just a simple bug in your code.

Comment: Edited to add code selections

Comment: Are you sure the value gets set to an actual number and not a string? To debug further I suggest putting some console logging inside `paymentNeeded` to check whether it is getting re-evaluated when the value changes.

Comment: If only I could find the facepalm emoji.